# Working with templates in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I have a template:

```
<template ngFor let-stat [ngForOf]='statistic'>
    <tr class="one">...</tr>
    <tr class="two">...</tr>
</template>
```

I want to move the template data as a single component:

Example:

```
<template ngFor let-stat [ngForOf]='statistic'>
    <statistic-item-view [statistic]="stat" [columns]="columns"></statistic-item-view>
</template>
```

Is there a way to change statistic-item-view on his template? It's a part of table and custom tags breaks all

tr is a valid table tag, statistic-view-item is not. I want to know is there a way to replace tag of its own template without rendering it inside tag?

Comment: @lllorian unclear question, what you mean by *change statistic-item-view on his template?* ?

Comment: @tchelidze  tr is a valid table tag, statistic-view-item is not. I want to know is there a way to replace tag of its own template without rendering it inside tag?

Comment: see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pHTrlnRNYijjzQYlRjto?p=preview)

Comment: @tchelidze It's not working for me. I decided to use multiple tbody

Comment: try to set `tr` as selector for you `statistic-item-view-component`

Comment: @tchelidze I have a few links on elem in second tr which I used in first tr. Because of it this scheme isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113245/discussion-between-illorian-and-tchelidze).